# %SystemRoot% seems to break PATH (Windows 7)

Tags: ruby, windows, path, environment-variables

The default PATH for Windows 7 is:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32; %SystemRoot%; %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
```

When my PATH environment variable is

```
%SystemRoot%; C:\Web\Ruby1.9.3\bin; C:\Web\Ruby1.9.3;
```

and I run `ruby-v` from the command-line, it states:

```
'ruby' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

When my PATH is instead

```
C:\Web\Ruby1.9.3\bin; C:\Web\Ruby1.9.3;
```

and I run `ruby -v`, the correct Ruby version is returned:

```
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22) [i386-mingw32]
```

Does anyone have a clue what's going on here?

NOTE:

- Moving `%SystemRoot%` to the RIGHT of my Ruby path makes ruby work, **but SystemRoot functions aren't recognized (for example, write.exe)**.
- `%SystemRoot%` is `C:\windows`. The default setting for Windows 7. I tried correcting the capitalization, but this didn't fix the issue.
- The default PATH is `%SystemRoot%\System32; %SystemRoot%; %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem`. I tried adding this back, but this also didn't fix the issue.

In case a little context helps: I have been developing Ruby/Rails for months now and there was no issue until last week, when suddenly something screwed up, about the time that I started looking into MongoDB.

Comment: I'm not sure that spaces are allowed.  Try getting rid of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you setting the path? I think you need to lose the quotes and spaces. i.e.

```
set path=%SystemRoot%;C:\Web\Ruby1.9.3\bin;C:\Web\Ruby1.9.3;
```

Comment: I originally set the path through windows advanced system settings (http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) - but also tried using SETX to no avail. True there aren't quotes - i updated the question to hopefully clear things up.

Comment: AH! PATH shouldn't have spaces between entries (derp!)
Changing my path to '%SystemRoot%;C:\Web\Ruby1.9.3\bin;C:\Web\Ruby1.9.3;' makes everything work swimmingly:

Comment: @corg. Thanks I improved the answer with your feedback.